# Adding tls-version parameter in mysql connection python

Tags: mysql-connector-python

while adding tls-versions parameter in mysql-connector-python(8.0.18), throwing exception as Unsupported argument 'tls_versions' at the time creating a connection.

```
db_config = {
    "user": "user",
    "password": "pwd",
    "database": "test",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "3306",
    "tls-versions": ["TLSv1.1"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `tls_versions` option is only available in 8.0.19. Please upgrade your Connector/Python installation.

Via pip (recommended way):

```
pip install --upgrade mysql-connector-python
```

Or with with the platform packages: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/